# (index):61 Uncaught ReferenceError: fnspeak1 is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have created a text to speech programm..and i get a error message which is give below
This is my program..

Html

```
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="fnspeak1()">
Play
</button>
```

Js

```
function fnspeak1()
{
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.getElementById("message").value);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

However when run..and when the play button is clicked:
I get a error message like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fnspeak1 is not defined
```

Can someone help me with this..Thanks in advance
Ps;i am a beginner in js

Comment: How are you loading or otherwise including the JavaScript code with your HTML?

Comment: Do you include the script file in the html file?

Comment: i have used js fiddle..

Comment: When does the error comes after you click on button ?

Comment: the error occurs after i click the button

Comment: This error is mostly raising, when a fatal error exists within the function. Will the same error raise when you remove line `window....`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should type more code for me to analyze.

1. `add window.onload = fnspeak1(){  your js code }`or Jquery `$(document).ready( your funciton here )`
2. is your function under other action? for example: `$(".a").on('click',function(){  your function })`
3. if your html and js not in one page ,have you included js in the right way?